Updating Eventbrite Event Full Description via API
I can't update the Full Description (not to be confused with the event summary) section of an event via their api. Their documentation seems pretty straightforward, however, it keeps returning a 200, but it doesn't update the page version number or modules. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Relevant Documentation: Doc 1 Doc 2
function addingEventDescription(eventId, currentEventDescription) {

  const data = {
    "modules":[
        {
          "type":"text",
          "data":{
              "body":{
                "type":"text",
                "text":"this is some fancy text",
                "alignment":"left"
              }
          }
        },
        {
          "type":"video",
          "data":{
              "video":{
                "url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pAz5X7ZW4",
                "display_size":"large"
              }
          }
        }
    ],
    "publish":true,
    "purpose":"listing"
  };


  // This must be incremented each time the event description is updated
  const url = `https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/${eventId}/structured_content/${currentEventDescription+1}`

  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(data),
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${eventBriteToken}`
    }
  };

  
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  const statusCode = response.getResponseCode();
  const content = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())

  if (statusCode != 200) {
    throw Error(`${statusCode} on ${url}\n${content.error}::${content.error_description}`)
  }
  return content;
}

addingEventDescription(980418226307,5)

In case it's helpful this is the response when I request the current full event description via the https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/${eventId}/structured_content/ endpoint:
{
  "resource_uris": {
    "self": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/980418226307/structured_content/5/",
    "add_module": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/980418226307/structured_content/5/module/",
    "publish": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/980418226307/structured_content/5/publish/",
    "preview_module": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/structured_content/module/preview/"
  },
  "access_type": "not-apply",
  "has_autogenerated_content": false,
  "hide_virtual_venue_content": false,
  "page_version_number": "5",
  "purpose": "listing",
  "modules": [
    {
      "resource_uris": {
        "self": "module/1541023419/"
      },
      "id": "1541023419",
      "type": "text",
      "layout": null,
      "data": {
        "body": {
          "text": "<p>Totes magotes like the best description evah</p>",
          "alignment": "left"
        },
        "display_restrictions": []
      },
      "semantic_purpose": "",
      "timed_display": null,
      "display_restrictions": []
    },
    {
      "resource_uris": {
        "self": "module/1541023429/"
      },
      "id": "1541023429",
      "type": "video",
      "layout": null,
      "data": {
        "display_restrictions": [],
        "video": {
          "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uom6RoyqFiE",
          "thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uom6RoyqFiE/default.jpg",
          "embed_url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/uom6RoyqFiE/"
        }
      },
      "semantic_purpose": "",
      "timed_display": null,
      "display_restrictions": []
    },
    {
      "resource_uris": {
        "self": "module/1541023439/"
      },
      "id": "1541023439",
      "type": "image",
      "layout": null,
      "data": {
        "display_restrictions": [],
        "image": {
          "edge_color_set": true,
          "edge_color": "#ffffff",
          "corner_style": "rectangular",
          "url": "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F822591399%2F52659637074%2F1%2Foriginal.20240807-193203?h=740&w=1200&auto=format%2Ccompress&q=75&sharp=10&s=616401026e53f08fb313d0de17fa8e76",
          "original": {
            "url": "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F822591399%2F52659637074%2F1%2Foriginal.20240807-193203?auto=format%2Ccompress&q=75&sharp=10&s=7e15898f3fbee413d4f877f59f6b13ae",
            "width": 992,
            "height": 1218
          },
          "focal_point": {},
          "image_id": "822591399",
          "crop_mask": {},
          "aspect_ratio": "0.8144499178981937602627257800",
          "id": "822591399"
        }
      },
      "semantic_purpose": "",
      "timed_display": null,
      "display_restrictions": []
    }
  ],
  "widgets": [],
  "pagination": {
    "object_count": 100,
    "page_number": 1,
    "page_size": 100,
    "page_count": 1
  }
}

